# Weird checkered css transition

Tags: html, css, transition, image-gallery

Im developing my own simple image gallery and im having some weird issues when the image is updated in the div container.

What its supposed to do is when the person clicks on one of the image buttons to see it enlarged, it fades to that image as seen on the thumbnail. What im having trouble with is that it fades AND does like a checkered transition at the same time.

[Take a look](http://cssdeck.com/labs/hzzzvem7)

What i tried doing is setting the child `li`'s and `div`'s `background-size` to `background-size: 600px 450px;` and `background-size: 100% 100%` but either one still makes the weird transition.

The only time it doesn't do the checkered transition is when no `background-size` is set to either elements.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is odd, but makes sense on some level...your two background images are different sizes. Setting the width to 100% is valid, but it *transitions* to that size as you have a CSS transition applied.

Comment: use `background-repeat:no-repeat;` on `li:nth-child(1)` & `li:nth-child(2)` I think that was you excepted

Comment: @SathishS You're a life saver! Thanks!. Put it as an answer and ill make sure to vote it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `background-repeat:no-repeat;` on `li:nth-child(1) & li:nth-child(2)` because you used image as a background so it repeated and then moved to 100%,

```
li:nth-child(1){
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/dT06PEZ.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
li:nth-child(2){
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/whcDsFy.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```